# why does my code stop exicution as soon as gui is imported and continue exicution as soon as gui is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

python seems to stop any further code execution when GUI is imported and the code after `import gui` is executed as soon as GUI is closed (using tkinter for GUI) why does this happen and how can i fix it ? my code ->

```
from click import cu1,cu2,du1,du2,idd
import gui

def dealsum ():
   global du1,du2,idd
   print("i am working")
   while True:
     print ("hiiii")
     if idd !=2 :
      if idd ==0:
        x1 = du1
        print("x1 ->"+str(x1))
        x2 = du2
        print("x2 ->"+str(x2))
        print ("interesting "+str(x1+x2))

dealsum ()
```

i tried making another file for the function `dealsum` and running it in other thread , i tried running gui on other thread . i was expecting running them on other thread would allow python to run code after importing gui

gui-> https://pastebin.com/Fc2XWpXt

Comment: How can we identify the issue without the code of `gui`?

Comment: i have added a pastebin link for gui

Comment: `root.mainloop()` is a infinity loop until the root window is closed.

Comment: how can i run other code along with it as i already tried multi threading

Comment: We are looking for a [mre], in the question itself, not a link to code you have done nothing to explain or debug.

Comment: You need to run `gui.py` as the main script instead and modify it to run `dealsum()` in a thread before calling `root.mainloop()`.